# JMeter XPath Extractor Issue

Tags: xpath, jmeter, extractor

I am trying to retrieve data from below XML but all the options i tried are giving me null value. Can someone please help!!!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns8:SearchQuoteResponse
            xmlns="http://services.akshay.com/pr/search" xmlns:ns2="http://services.akshay.com/pr/po"
            xmlns:ns3="http://services.akshay.com/pr/common"
            xmlns:ns4="http://services.akshay.com/pr/fault"
            xmlns:ns5="http://services.akshay.com/pr/appointment"
            xmlns:ns6="http://services.akshay.com/pr/registration"
            xmlns:ns7="http://services.akshay.com/pr/in"
            xmlns:ns8="http://services.akshay.com/Services/ws"
            xmlns:ns9="http://services.akshay.com/pr/q">
            <ns8:responseType>SUCCESS</ns8:responseType>
            <ns8:message>Quote Search completed successfully.</ns8:message>
            <ns9:Quote>
                <ns9:quoteId>72620</ns9:quoteId>
                <ns9:quoteResponse>
                    <ns9:quoteExpiryDate>2013-08-04T10:17:35.000Z</ns9:quoteExpiryDate>
                    <ns9:listQuoteItemResponse>
                        <ns9:respQuoteItemId>657222</ns9:respQuoteItemId>
                        <ns9:lineNumber>1</ns9:lineNumber>
                        <ns9:afterMarketPartDetails>
                            <ns3:warrantyType />
                        </ns9:afterMarketPartDetails>
                        <ns9:listPrice>153.0</ns9:listPrice>
                        <ns9:netPrice>61.2</ns9:netPrice>
                        <ns9:partAvailability>IN</ns9:partAvailability>
                        <ns9:shippable>Y</ns9:shippable>
                    </ns9:listQuoteItemResponse>
                </ns9:quoteResponse>
                <ns9:createdDate>2013-06-20T16:17:34.996Z</ns9:createdDate>
            </ns9:Quote>
        </ns8:SearchQuoteResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

From the above SOAP i need value of `<ns9:respQuoteItemId></ns9:respQuoteItemId>` tag, but XPath Extractor always gives me null value.
I have tried below options -

```
1 - //*[local-name()="respQuoteItemId"]/text()
2 - //*[local-name()='respQuoteItemId' and namespace-uri()='http://services.myportal.com/procurement/q']
3 - //ns8:SearchQuoteResponse/ns9:Quote/ns9:quoteResponse/ns9:listQuoteItemResponse/ns9:respQuoteItemId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third answer is the closest, but it is missing `/ns9:quoteResponse/` in the middle to be complete.

Comment: My Bad, it was typo while posting, even with that Tag it gives me Null value :(

Comment: Then I cannot see why the item isn't being found.  I suggest you review your namespace bindings for the prefixes being used in the expression.  Good luck!

Comment: Just to add more i am getting below Exception when i am trying 3rd option. Assertion failure message: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns8

Comment: Right ... as I said, your namespace prefixes need to be bound to the same URI strings as used in the XML source.

Answer (score 1):

Read this :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion

  ```
  To overcome Xalan XPath parser implementation on which JMeter is based, you can 
  help the parsing by providing a Properties file which will contain:
  - prefix1=Full Namespace 1
  - prefix2=Full Namespace 2
  ...

  You reference this file in user.properties file using the property:
  - xpath.namespace.config=<path to your properties file>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i followed all the step but unable to get it resolved. The Namespace works fine for other Tag's its only the <ns9:listQuoteItemResponse> failing :(

Comment: Show the configuration you set up for namespaces?

Comment: Thanks PMD, I forgot to post, somehow it started working with the 3rd option i put in my questions. Thanks for your Help!!!